# Living Spell and Mage's Disjunction

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, monsters

There is a dillema about Living Spell ooze: since it is an awakened spell, how does Disjunction effect it? (And will at all?). Should it take damage from anti-magic field (like elemental would on opposite plane) or should it be thought of as ooze only?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please tag your questions with care; in particular, there are many different RPG systems out there, so we need to know which you are using. I have guessed, from context, that it was D&D 3.5, but feel free to fix that if I guessed wrong. You should take a look at our [Tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about/), and once you get 20 reputation, feel free to join us in the [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat)!

Answer (score 3):

[This article here](http://community.wizards.com/forum/eberron/threads/1175661) lists a number of *Living Spell* oozes.  Notably, only the one for Antimagic Field lists any vulnerability to *Disjunction*, and that is consistent with [the normal rules for that spell](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD%3aAntimagic_Field).  It is thus safe to say that ***Disjunction* does not normally effect *Living Spell* oozes**.

Comment: As an addendum, it’s important to note that Living Spells, despite the name, are *creatures* under the rules. They behave like creatures do. The template is applied to a spell, but it turns the spell into a creature based on that spell. The only ways it behaves like that spell are the ways listed explicitly in the template (e.g. triggering the spell on natural attacks, etc.) For anything not listed, they behave like any other ooze.